# Air Resistance In this simulation causes the velocity to rise drastically

Tags: java, processing, simulation, physics

The issue I have is that I'm attempting to add drag to an object in this basic physics simulation (Java [Processing]), but once I add the appropriate formula, it causes the objects velocity to increase drastically in the opposite direction. Of course the problem is that drag for some reason is being calculated too high but I'm not sure why thats happening as I'm using the real world equation.

```
void setup(){size(1280,720);}

class Circle{
  float x,y,r,m,dx,dy,ax,ay,fx,fy;
  Circle(float xPos, float yPos, float Radius, float Mass){
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
    r = Radius;
    m = Mass;
  }
  
  void ADD_DRAG(){
    fx -= 0.5 * 1.225 * dx * dx * 0.5 * r * PI;
    fy -= 0.5 * 1.225 * dy * dy * 0.5 * r * PI;
  
  }
  
  void update(){
    ADD_DRAG();
    ax = fx / m;
    ay = fy / m;
    
    dx += ax / frameRate;
    dy += ay / frameRate;
    
    x += dx / frameRate;
    y += dy / frameRate;
  }
}

Circle[] SceneObjects = {new Circle(50,50,20,20000),new Circle(50,50,2,20)};



void draw(){
   background(51);
   
   for (Circle c : SceneObjects){
     c.update();
     circle(c.x * 3,c.y * 3,c.r * 3);  
   }  
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(SceneObjects[1].fx != 2000)
    SceneObjects[1].fx = 2000;
  else
    SceneObjects[1].fx = 0;
}
```

This is the code, essentially there is a Circle class which stores the objects properties and then the forces applies are updated each draw loop. The mouseClicked void is just for testing by adding a force to the objects. All and any help is appreciated, thanks!

Maths I am Using:
Rearranged F=ma for `ax = fx / m;`
Acceleration * time = Speed for `dx += ax / frameRate;` (frameRate is 1/time)
Distance = Speed * time = for `x += dx / frameRate;` (same as above)
For drag im using this equation https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/rocket/drageq.html with the constants eg air density etc added as seen.

Comment: i'm no expert, but are you supposed to be integrating the gradients?

Comment: I thought because dx and dy are the speed as in m/s dividing by framerate would give meters as framerate is 1/s. Isnt the integral just a different way of doing the same thing?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want the net x and y, you could definitely do integrate x (+= ) but integrating dx and dy doesn't make sense to me at least. Could you edit the post with a link to the math you're using?

Comment: I've added the maths. Also just incase fx = force ax = acceleration dx = speed x = position, I dont feel like I explained that, thanks!

Comment: Also this website that shows how the integral of velocity related to acceleration https://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

You haven't given us numbers (or a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but the vector algebra is off.

Yes, the acceleration is **f** = -k**v**<sup>2</sup>, and |**v**|<sup>2</sup> = v<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + v<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>, but that doesn't mean that you can decompose **f** into f<sub>x</sub>=kv<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> and f<sub>y</sub>=kv<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>. Not only is your magnitude off, but your acceleration is now not (in general) aligned with the motion; the path of your projectile will tend to *curve* toward a diagonal between the axes (e.g. x=y).

Also, your code always gives acceleration in the negative x and negative y directions. If your projectile happens to start out going that way, your version of air resistance will *speed it up.*

Finally, your time interval may simply be too large.

There is a better way. The differential equation is **v**' = -k **v**|**v**|, and the exact solution is **v** = (1/kt) **z**, (with appropriate choice of the starting time) where **z** is the unit direction vector. (I don't know how to put a caret over a letter.) This leads to **v**(t) = (1/t)**v**(t=1.0)

So you can either work out a fictional time t<sub>0</sub> and calculate each new velocity using 1/(kt), or you can calculate the new velocity from the previous velocity: v<sub>n+1</sub> =v<sub>n</sub>/(kd v<sub>n</sub> + 1), where d is the time interval. (And then of course you have to decompose **v** into v<sub>x</sub> and v<sub>y</sub> properly.)

If you're not familiar with vector algebra, this may seem confusing, but you can't get an air-resistance sim to work without learning the basics.